# Python joining strings

Tags: python, string

I have run into a problem joining two strings in Python.
I have some code that is like this:

```
for line in sites:
    site = line        

    for line in files:
        url = site+line
```

That should be easy I thougth but the strings ends up "looking wierd":

http://example.com/  (this is the site)
history.txt          (Then the line comes on another "line" in the strings which screws it up when I try to open the url because it is invalid)

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "looking weird"?  The only strange thing about your code is using the iterator name "line" in the nested loop - but that shouldn't cause a problem with your code.

Comment: I think your site link is broken. Please also post what the strings look like. Putting the input data in the question itself would also be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean "looking weird"? What is the content of the variables sites and files? What do you mean by 'Then the line comes on another "line" in the strings'?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want and what you get?  I.e. I want http://example.com/history.txt and get http://example.com/http://example2.com

Comment: Does this help?
>>> ', '.join(str(x) for x in range(10))
'0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'

Comment: This is the real url "http://127.0.0.1/" and it is valid.
if I try to print the string after joining them it would print out like this:
http://127.0.0.1/
history.txt
using two seperate lines which will cause a invalid url when opening it.

Comment: What Iam looking for is joining the two strings so it would look like this: hxxp://127.0.0.1/history.txt. What happends is that the string gets seperated over 2 lines and then the url becoms invalid. I think the problem may come from the files it reads the different strings from.

Comment: @pyCtrl_: do not comment on your own question.  That's silly.  UPDATE your question to include all the necessary information. Then DELETE your comments.  Please UPDATE your question to make it clear and complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to avoid using the same variable in the for statements:

```
for site in sites:
  for line in files:
     url = site + line
```

Does that clear things up?  It is good practice in any case.

Comment: if "sites" is a file the line ending \n\r is NOT stripped by the for construct

Comment: Thanks, a combination of that and gnibbler's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have extra whitespace for example a newline at the end of the site

```
for site in sites:
    for line in files:
        url = site.strip() + line.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is in using the identifier name 'line' twice?